# Unable to browse webpage using driver.get() function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying browse [webpage](https://www.adv1wheels.com/product/adv08-flowspec-wheels/) scrape data off it. I have couple more links along with mentioned link which work on a for loop. However, unlike other links when get() function tries to access this like it gives me the error below:

Code statement:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="..\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")

def page_content_extractor(given_line):

    print('in page content extractor function. Given link is : ',given_line)
    try:
        driver.get(given_line)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception occurred !! Find these links under rogue links')
        print(e)

    time.sleep(2)
```

Exception statement:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x006FD953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x0068F5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x0057C6B8+837304]
    Ordinal0 [0x0056EB34+781108]
    Ordinal0 [0x0056E06A+778346]
    Ordinal0 [0x0056D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x0056CEBC+773820]
    Ordinal0 [0x0056CD59+773465]
    Ordinal0 [0x0057DA70+842352]
    Ordinal0 [0x005CAB6F+1157999]
    Ordinal0 [0x005C4463+1131619]
    Ordinal0 [0x0059E860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x0059F756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0096CC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0078EABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0078D916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00695F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x0069A898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x0069A985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x006A3AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7660FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B07A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B07A6E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

one more thing to mention here is that this exception is not thrown for other urls. No sure whats really wrong here or how to handle it. Tried using try-except but even that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is driver? where did you pass it in?

Comment: Thats chrome webdriver object. Just added it up there.

Comment: Its a global variable. So far never caused any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download latest chrome driver file of version and use it project. Update your desktop to Latest chrome version (Right side three dots option>>Help>> About Chrome and use the chromedriver exe from below path which is supportive to you chrome version.

Chrome driver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Tried doing that. Code did not brake there but still Exceptions occurred. Curious part is that none other URLs have had any issues except his and one other.

Comment: Can you share the URL. If URL does not contains https:// the also it breaks. Open URL in browser and copy that URL in copy that URL and paste in code then try.